Need to exclude checksiteNode parameter specified in the appsettings.json while releasing in the azure devops
We have a DTAP (DEv, Test, Acc and Prod) environments, and when we do a release in the env's for node specific. (In Acc and PROD I have 3 nodes), while trying to create a release in Azure DevOps,the appsettings.json file also get deployed to the env specific.
My Issue is in Acc and PROD while deploying the appsettings.json file to the ACC nodes the checksitenode parameter should get excluded as it is node specific
Node1
"CheckSiteNode": "This is node 1.",

Node 2
"CheckSiteNode": "This is node 2.",

Node 3
"CheckSiteNode": "This is node 3.",

Should be like the above specifics to nodes.
Appreciate your help, how to exclude the parameter in Azure Devops release pipeline.
I tried to configure a task - File transform
Package or folder - specified the path of the package
Checked XML transformation
Transformation rules- created a appsettings.json.transform and mentioned below code
 <configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="CheckSiteNode" value="**EXCLUDE THIS**"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>

In variable substitution, File format selected as JSON
Target Files- appsettings.json

Can you share the appsettings.json content? And how do you deploy the json(which task)? You mentioned you want to exclude the parameter, but also mentioned to like checksitenote specific to nodes, could you please elaborate a bit of your expectation?

Do you want a new appsettings.json with new value, deploy to each node?

Hi @wadezhou-MSFT,
have configured the tasks -(IIS web app manage) specifying the website physical path and (IIS web app deploy), by mentioning the path of the artifact
yes, whenever there are changes to the appsettings.json file it should get deployed and the checksite node value should get updated as per node.

The web app task mentioned is similar to FileTransform task, only supports transfer XML files not JSON. Please check my previous comment and reply for the details. To resolve your issue, you need to share the appsettings.json content details, so we can check  if it's able to replace variable value(JSON variable substitution).

The FileTransform@2 task is used to replace tokens with variable values in XML or JSON configuration files. At present, file transformations are supported for only XML files, not JSON file.

You should not use **EXCLUDE THIS** for the CheckSiteNode value, instead, you can replace the value in the task, so that correct appsettings.json content will be deployed to target node.
Sample below:
- task: FileTransform@2
  displayName: Replace Unit Tests appsettings.json
  inputs:
    folderPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/Steam.UnitTests'  #<-- specify the json file path
    xmlTransformationRules:                #<-- remove value as cannot transform json file.
    jsonTargetFiles: 'appsettings.json'     #<---- specify json file name

Define variable CheckSiteNode in pipeline(notice nested or hierarchical).
If you are deploying each job in different job, you can add the same variable in each job with different value, so that different appsettings.json will be deployed to each node.
If you are deploying nodes in one job, you can use logging command to update the variable value, apply file transform and deploy to target node.

